# Template Cache ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, caching, express

I am having some difficulty with template caching in my MEAN app. I have a navigation bar that is using conditional logic to show/hide the buttons displayed to the user. When a user hits the page, the values will be set to null or false, but once they login, those values will change (views, isLoggedIn)

My problem is this- When I hit the page for the first time, the values are set either as null/false as expected, and buttons are hidden.

However, after a successful login, the angular login controller is doing a redirect via `$location.path("/pathAfterLogin");` and bringing the user to the correct state but with the hidden buttons. Only after I do a hard refresh ( control-f5 ) does the page refresh and show the appropriate buttons based on the values set in the app.js file.

I am using Angular 1.5, UI-Router, [Express 4](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.disable), [Swig templates](https://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/), and the [consolidate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate) template engine. The NODE.ENV is set to development.

I have also tried disabling the cache every place I can think of.

My app.js file looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    swig = require('swig');


module.exports = function() {
    var app = express(); //start an express app app.disable('view cache');

    app.engine('html', cons.swig);

    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'../app/views'));
    app.set('view cache', false ); //set cache

    swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });

    app.get('*', stuff.test, function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        res.render('index', {
            cache: false,
            views: req.views,
            isLoggedIn: req.isLoggedIn
        });
    });
        return app;
};
```

The HTML file is my main layout/view, as this is a single page application with URL re-rewriting turned on. the index.html file below is *including* a navigation file as well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    ( truncated ... )
</head>

<body>
<header>{% include "../../public/templates/header.html" %}</header>
<header>{% include "../../public/templates/navigation.html" %}</header>
<div class="res whitespace">

        <ui-view/>
</div>

</body>
<script src = "angular.js"></script>
<script src = "loginCtrl.js"></script>
<script src = "loginSrvc.js"></script>
</html>
```

Included navigation file:

```
<div id="subtitle">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        {% if !isLoggedIn %}<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="login">Login</a></li>{% endif %}
        {% if isLoggedIn %}<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="logout">Logout</a></li>{% endif %}
        {% for item in views %}
            {% if item == "linkA" %}<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="linkA">LinkA</a></li>{% endif %}
            {% if item == "LinkB" %}<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="linkB">LinkB</a></li> {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if !isLoggedIn %}<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="info">Info </a></li>{% endif %}
        <li class="dropdown"ui-sref-active="active">
            {% for item in views %}
                {% if resource == "mainDD" %} <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Drop Downs <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    {% for item in permissions %}
                        {% if item == "link1" %}<li><a ui-sref="link1">Link 1</a></li>{% endif %}
                        {% if item == "link2" %}<li><a ui-sref="link2">Link 2</a></li>{% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    </
```

ul>

I have 2 questions:

1. Is the caching turned off appropriately? If not, where am I going wrong?
2. Is this expected behavior when caching is turned off?

Comment: How exactly are you logging in? You're saying that _"after a successful login, the angular login controller is doing a redirect via `$location.path("/pathAfterLogin")`"_, which sounds like you're logging in through an AJAX call. Which generally won't trigger a full rerender of a server-side template.

Comment: Correct. I am using $http.post (from Angular) to submit the user credentials to the Node server, and then returning a true/false value if the user is logged in. What would I need to do instead to trigger a full re-render of a server side template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're mixing backend templating with frontend routing:

```
{% if isLoggedIn %}<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="logout">Logout</a></li>{% endif %}
```

`isLoggedIn` is a server-side variable that is used to determine if its contents (the `<li>`) should be shown in the generated HTML.

If the user wasn't logged in at the time the HTML was generated, only a full (server-side) re-render of the template will cause the *"Logout"* button to appear in the HTML that gets served to the browser.

To work around this, you need to reload the page (I haven't used Angular in quite a while, but `$window.location.reload()` used to work) so the server gets a chance to provide the updated HTML.

Alternatively, you can consider moving the templating logic on whether or not to show particular page elements to Angular:

```
<li ng-if="loggedIn" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="logout">Logout</a></li>
```

(where `loggedIn` is a variable in your controller)

To be clear: this has nothing to do with caching. View caching in Express doesn't cache rendered templates (ie the HTML), but the *compiled* template (generally, a template has to be read from file, processed or "compiled", and then it's ready to use for rendering).

Comment: The alternative was what I considered first, however, it allows the user to see the buttons and actions they can or cannot perform, because the angular side still shows the HTML. The express template does not. Windows.location.reload will reload the state, but I want to re-download the HTML and Redirect at the same time. I'm not sure if that will allow both actions.

Comment: Try using `$window.location.href = '/pathAfterLogin'` instead of using `$location`.